# Detect faces without eyebrows and jaw using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, face-detection, eye-detection

I am trying to detect faces (specifically, faces with opened eyes) using OpenCV haar cascade classifier. However, I had a problem detecting the faces that do not have eyebrows and/or jaw, as shown in the following image. I had tried many haar cascade for face detection such as *haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml*, *haarcascade_frontalface_alt_tree.xml*, etc. But all of these did not work.

[image] [image]

Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import os
import glob

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml')

count = 0
path = "./test/*.png"
for index, filename in enumerate(glob.glob(path)):
    img = cv2.imread(filename)
    basename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(filename))[0]

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        # cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w, y+h),(255,0,0), 2)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)

        if len(eyes) >= 2:
            count = count + 1
            output_dir = './test/output'
            cv2.imwrite(f'{output_dir}/{basename}.png', img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Use facial landmarks with `dlib`, this method may work for you, see these two links:

- [facial-landmarks-dlib-opencv-python](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/04/03/facial-landmarks-dlib-opencv-python/)
- [opencv-face-recognition](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/24/opencv-face-recognition/)

Also, see this link:

- [dlib-and-deep-learning](https://www.learnopencv.com/face-detection-opencv-dlib-and-deep-learning-c-python/)

Answer (score 0):

If you have tensorflow installed you can use a neural net to detect faces which give much better accuracy than the simple haar classifier.

Here's an example using the MTCNN detector which uses tensorflow as the backend.

```
from mtcnn.mtcnn import MTCNN
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

img = Image.open('6qNFu.png') # load the image
img = np.asarray(img, dtype='uint8') # convert to numpy array
img = img[:,:,0:3] # drop the alpha channel

detector = MTCNN() # initialize MTCNN detector
print(detector.detect_faces(img)) # use MTCNN detector to return bounding box and face metrics
```

Using the bounding box you can extract the face from the image. Note: if the face is truncated like in the instances above, it might return a negative coordinate which is an extrapolation of where it thinks the face might be.

Here is a the documentation on MTCNN library: https://pypi.org/project/mtcnn/
It also tells you how to install it.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work better than haar classifier and can detect both opened and closed eyes. Anyway, since I have a lot of images and I want to select only images with opened eyes, how can I achieve this?